# How to get the files which are not in database

Tags: php, mysql

let me describe my problem as clear as i can.
1st. i have the following table on my database

```
 ------------------
 | id |    url    |
 ------------------
 | 1  | file1.mp3 |
 ------------------
 | 2  | file2.mp3 |
 ------------------
 | 3  | file3.mp3 |
 ------------------
```

2nd. i have the following files on my directory (named "datas")

```
 file1.mp3
 file2.mp3
 file3.mp3
 file4.mp3
 file5.mp3
```

3rd. now my problem
how i would be able to get the files (file4.mp3 and file5.mp3) which are not in database.     to get all the files from datas directory i'm using the following codes

```
 $dir = "datas/";
 $files = glob($dir . "*.mp3");
 foreach($files as $file)
   {
     echo $file."<br />";
   }
```

hope u get it, what i'm looking for... thanx in advance for ur help.

Comment: You want to get the files from where ?

Comment: Do you want compare which files are missing in the database but available in the directory ?

Comment: Yes i want to compare the files which are missing in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea, that you may adopt (I'm using procedural `mysqli`)

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","yourpassword","database_name");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select url from table_name");
$db_files = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $db_files[] = 'datas/' . $row['image'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
print_r($db_files);
```

**Output:** (`$db_files`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => datas/file1.mp3
    [1] => datas/file2.mp3
    [2] => datas/file3.mp3
)
```

Now the `glob`

```
$dir = "datas/";
$files = glob($dir . "*.mp3");
print_r($files);
```

**Output:** (`$files`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => datas/file1.mp3
    [1] => datas/file2.mp3
    [2] => datas/file3.mp3
    [3] => datas/file4.mp3
    [4] => datas/file5.mp3
)
```

Now, you can use

```
$missing = array_diff($files, $db_files);
print_r($missing);
```

**Output:** (`$missing`)

```
Array ( 
    [3] => datas/file4.mp3
    [4] => datas/file5.mp3
)
```

So, you can loop it like

```
foreach($missing as $missing_file) {
    echo "$missing_file is not in database<br />";
}
```

**Output:**

```
datas/file4.mp3 is not in database
datas/file5.mp3 is not in database
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the results from the SQL into an array

The the results from the glob into an array

And compare the two arrays and store what is lacking from `array SQL` in `array glob` and vica versa

Comment: thnx, i was on the same track for 2 hours to get it work, but i'm totally confuse how to code it..

Comment: You got the SQL? because your glob is already 45% of the work, SQL 45% the rest 10% is the array comparison, which is easy in php see ``array_diff``

Comment: i'm using the following to get the records from database but no idea what to put in while statment.

$sql = "SELECT url FROM files";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
    
   }

Comment: Don't fetch rows, fetch everything into an array

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all perform sql connectivity, query and populate a array $dbfiles with files names.
2. Then modify your code's loop as :

   `foreach($files as $file)
    {
     if(!in_array($file,$dbfiles))
     {
        echo $file."<br>;
     }
   }`

for more on **in_array** see reference:

[http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thnx dear....
i'm using the following codes and getting all the files from my directory also getting the file which are in database.
 $dir ="files/";
 $files = glob($dir . "*.mp3");
 $sql = "SELECT url FROM songs";
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
    $resultDB[] = $row['url'];
   }
 foreach($files as $file) {
  if(!in_array($file, $resultDB))
   {
    echo $file."<br />";
   }
 }

Comment: I am unable to figure out.. use `echo var_dump($array)` before loop. watch value of both array `$files` and `$resultDB`.